# @username is non-existent or unavailable

Tags: ruby, variables, sinatra, instance-variables

http://bpaste.net/show/6888fe224663

Why is @username non-existent or unavailable at

`get '/user/:username' do
  puts @username
  'hello'
end`

It's an instance variable so I assumed it'd be accessible at the point of the `puts`. However, it's not printing to the console. What's a better/working way?

Comment: Because you haven't assigned it... Also, this isn't Rails...

Comment: Misunderstood instance vars in ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get your parameters.

```
get '/user/:username' do |username|
  puts username
  'hello'
end
```

or

```
get '/user/:username' do 
  puts params["username"]
  'hello'
end
```